# Excel return text stopping at character

Tags: excel

I have a excel extract which I need to use to do a VLOOKUP, my problem is that the names between the two spreadsheet are not perfect matches.. for example on the main spreadsheet:

```
|File|
|-|
Test File 1|
Test File 2|
Test File 3|
Test File 4|
Dummy File 59|
Dummy File 21|
Ostrich|
```

But the table I am looking up against has the following:

```
|File|
|-|
DRIVE/FOLDER LOCATOIN/Test File 1|
ROOT/DESTINATION FOLDER/Test File 2|
DRIVE/FOLDER LOCATOIN/Test File 3|
DRIVE/Test File 4|
FOLDER LOCATOIN/Dummy File 59|
DRIVE/FOLDER/LOCATOIN/Dummy File 21|
DRIVE/FOLDE- LOCATOIN/Ostrich|
```

I am curious if their is a way to pull just the text from the right stopping at the first "/"
Normally I would just use a =RIGHT formula but since each line has a different amount of characters I need this is a little impossible

Comment: After lookup what result do you want to return? Full string? What is your excel version? Still you can use `RIGHT()` function but `FILTERXML()` may best fit for this case.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clearer on the results that I was after, so the list that has the naming conventions DRIVE/FOLDER LOCATOIN/Test File 1 contains how many time each file has been accessed, so I have done a count for this.

Answer (score 0):

combine what you have done with a find("/", cell_number)

Answer (score 0):

Use wild-card to find the match that ends with your `lookup_value`

```
eg:  =VLOOKUP("*" &A1,$O$1:$O$10,1,FALSE)
```